# Regex for extracting resource name from ARN

Tags: regex, regex-group, amazon-elb

I'm trying to create a regex to extract the resource name from all resources ARNs.
There are these ARN structures:

```
arn:aws:service:region:accountnumber:resourcename
arn:aws:service:region:accountnumber:resourcetype/resourcename
arn:aws:service:region:accountnumber:resourcetype:resourcename
```

For these I've found [this regex in regex101](https://regex101.com/library/pOfxYN):

```
^arn:(?P<Partition>[^:\n]*):(?P<Service>[^:\n]*):(?P<Region>[^:\n]*):(?P<AccountID>[^:\n]*):(?P<Ignore>(?P<ResourceType>[^:\/\n]*)[:\/])?(?P<Resource>.*)$
```

But I've found out there's also a special case for load balancer where the above regex doesn't work. for example:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:accountnumber:loadbalancer/net/resourcename/alphanumeric
```

The only solution I could find has 2 match groups and after using the regex I need to check if Group2 has a match, if not then to use Group1:

```
\:[^\/]*[\/\:]([^\/]+)$|([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+$
```

I'm trying to find a regex with a single group which will extract the resource name.

** For S3 (or any other resource), I don't need to support ARN + subfolder. only the S3 ARN.

Answer (score 1):

If the part in the ignore can be preceded by a pattern like `loadbalancer/net` you might append an optional part in the `Ignore` group:

```
^arn:(?P<Partition>[^:\n]*):(?P<Service>[^:\n]*):(?P<Region>[^:\n]*):(?P<AccountID>[^:\n]*):(?P<Ignore>(?:[^\/\n]*\/[^\/\n]*)?(?P<ResourceType>[^:\/\n]*)[:\/])?(?P<Resource>.*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f7uhkE/1)